# New Angular 2 CLI tool - Systemjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, mean-stack

## Summary

- Wanting clarificaiton on missing systemjs.config.js file with the new
  Angular2 CLI setup tool.
- How do I install barebones Angular 2? Angular.io seems to only offer the CLI tool now.

## Background

I had built an angular 2 applicaiton for a membership database. This was only the front end. After learning about backend development I realized a MEAN stack is best aligned with my skillset so I am now making RESTful APi using Node and express.js.

I am using the following in my server.js file to load my index.html.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I had a seperate folder for my API but I want it all on one code base (MEAN stack). I decided, lets just use the new angular stuff that was released last week and rebuild my folder structure for the front end (should be a matter of moving files around)**.....  I was wrong**

When visiting the site, all I see is this CLI tool. It however installs everything like Jasmine, E2E etc. This is great and all but I don't understand that stuff yet and would just like to install the bare bones so I can run my app.

## The Question

However, poking around I see that with the cli setup **there is no systemjs file. Where did it go?** also in my index.html file I had:

```
  <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

**This is also not included** in the index.html that was in create with the CLI tool.

## The Ask

Lots seemed to have changed. Can anyone shed some light on these changes and perhaps reference a good setup guide for bare-bones of the new angular 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI team has ditched `SystemJS` and decided to switch to `WebPack`. The CLI tool is now quite fast(`1.0.0-beta.28.3`) compared to using SystemJS which now takes an average of 2secs to re-compile(on subsequent compilations). In my opinion, the CLI is the tool to go for building Angular 2 projects.

FYI: `Angular 4` is coming out in March, which is just a `Semver` adaptation which usually means there will be "some" breaking changes. [source](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/the-next-version-of-angular-is-angular-v4)

Comment: What confused me is that the CLI tool creats only this in the index.html

`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angularcli</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: When you build the project with `ng build --prod` it will inject all the necessary script references into the `index.html` file

Comment: I am so lost though, I am trying to run the index.html through express.js.

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` , however this won't work because I launch my server.js with nodemon server.js which won;t build or serve my front end. How am I suppose to build a MEAN stack now?

Comment: It doesn't mean you have to put everything in a single project folder. Just separate your `Angular 2` project from your `express` project. Angular will run on `localhost:4200` by default, and have your angular app point to whatever address your node server is running when consuming the API. Later on, when you are done working on your `Angular 2`, you can `ng build --prod` on it which will generate all static files for your app, generated in `dist` folder of your project. You can then move them into your `express` project in production

Comment: Right on, your answer helped me look up the process. 

https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Huge help, thank you